small exercise regarding the on of limit superior
Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers. Recall that a point of accumulation of the sequence is a number $x$ such that given $\epsilon >0$, there exists infinitely many indices $n$ such that $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$.
Suppose now that $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence. Let $S$ be the set of points of accumulation.
We define the limit superior of the sequence to be
$\lambda:=lim sup x_n$= least upper bound of $S$.
Exercise:
Verify that $\lambda$ itself is a accumulation point of the sequence and is therefore the largest such point.
Attempt:
Since $(x_n)$ is bounded, there is at least one accumulation point.
The set $S$ is defined as the set of accumulation points of $(x_n)$ and $\lambda := \sup (S)$.
Since $\lambda := \sup (S)$, we know that
(1) $\lambda$ is upper bound for $S$, and
(2) for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists $s \in S$ such that $\lambda-\epsilon<s$.
From conidion (2) we get that, for any $\epsilon >0$, we can find $s \in S$ such that $|\lambda -s |<\epsilon$.
Since $s\in S$, i.e. is an accumulation point of $(x_n)$ there exist infinitely many indices $n$ such that $|s-x_n|<\epsilon$.
Thus we get $|\lambda -x_n|=|\lambda -s+s-x_n|\leq |\lambda -s|+|s-x_n|<2 \epsilon$.
I want to know if this apporach is correct.
I have some doubt (just a little bit) since if I think of a set of accumulation points of a sequence, i think of some discrete set. So in this case , sup $S$=max $S$ and $\lambda=s$. Thus what I showed would have been trivial.

This exercise is indeed to show that the set of accumulation points has a maximum. A priori, you do not know that. For an example of a sequence whose accumulation points are not discrete, consider an enumeration of the rationals between $0$ and $1$.
